# Field 'id' expected a number but got 'abdullah123'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to get balance from the UserBalance table filter by username.

I have tried using `UserBalance.objects.filter(username=username)` where I am actually getting error.

```
    #views.py
    
        def login_validation(request):
            if request.method=='POST':
                username=request.POST.get("username")
                password=request.POST.get("password")
                user=auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        
        
                if user is not None:
                    auth.login(request, user)
                    user_balance=UserBalance.objects.filter(username=username) #error_i_am_getting_here
                    return render(request, "homepage.html", {'name':username, 'balance':user_balance})
                else:
                    return redirect("http://google.com/")
        
            else:
                return redirect("http://yahoo.com/")
    
    
    #models.py
    
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    
    class IncomeExpense(models.Model):
        entry_type=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        amount=models.IntegerField()
        details=models.TextField()
        capture_date=models.DateField()
        username=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    class UserBalance(models.Model):
        balance=models.IntegerField()
        username=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have pasted views.py and models.py code. I tried using filter with username and it's giving an error and I tried using get method also...but again getting same error. Also please explain me how get and filter works

Comment: Show us your UserBalance model i suspect username is foreign key right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use:

```
username=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`username` is not really a username;  It is a `User`.  So, you have to query for the User given the `user`, like:

```
user_balance=UserBalance.objects.filter(username=user)
```

(Of course, you should change the `username` fields in your models to `user`, but this answers the question).

Here is better code:

```
    #views.py
    
        def login_validation(request):
            if request.method=='POST':
                username=request.POST.get("username")
                password=request.POST.get("password")
                user=auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        
        
                if user is not None:
                    auth.login(request, user)
                    user_balance=UserBalance.objects.filter(user=user) #error_i_am_getting_here
                    return render(request, "homepage.html", {'name':user.username, 'balance':user_balance})
                else:
                    return redirect("http://google.com/")
        
            else:
                return redirect("http://yahoo.com/")
    
    
    #models.py
    
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    
    class IncomeExpense(models.Model):
        entry_type=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        amount=models.IntegerField()
        details=models.TextField()
        capture_date=models.DateField()
        user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    class UserBalance(models.Model):
        balance=models.IntegerField()
        user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. My issue got resolved... i marked this question as resolved

Answer (score 0):

The `username` field of the `UserBalance` model is a `ForeignKey` to `User`. So when you do a `filter` or `get` on this field, you can't do it using a string username. You either have to pass an entire `User` instance, or the (integer) id of such an instance.

To get the `UserBalance`s of users with a particular username, you therefore need to first find all `User` instances with that username, then find all `UserBalance`s with a `username` field that matches one of those. And you could do this with two separate queries - but it's obviously more efficient to do so in one query, which Django allows with its intuitive [query API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):
`user_balance=UserBalance.objects.filter(username__username=username)`

And if that looks confusing (which it does!), that's because your `ForeignKey` field is misnamed as `username` when it should be simply something like `user`.

Comment: thanks for your answer...i am getting the value as this...<QuerySet [<UserBalance: UserBalance object (1)>]>

Comment: i tried this --> user_balance = UserBalance.objects.filter(username__username=username).values_list('balance', flat=True)....but i am getting this as a output Your Total Balance is <QuerySet [1000]>

Comment: i got the output...by doing UserBalance.objects.filter(username__username=username).values_list('balance', flat=True)[0]

Comment: Thanks for your time...I got my issue resolved.i marked my question as resolved